# Having troubles with pip and importing

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have both Python 3.5 and Python 2.7 installed. I install tweepy via CMD using " python -m pip install tweepy", yet when I import tweepy in either IDLE 2.7 or 3.5, I get the error "Module not installed", even though CMD says it has downloaded and installed it properly.

What could be the error, as I think this may have been the solution to my last projects hiccup I couldn't fix.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Launch python 2.7 and type

`>>>import tweepy`

Than launch python 3.5 and type

```
>>>import tweepy
```

Whichever one does not work means that is probably not your default Python installation.

One of your Python installations doesn't have this installed since pip does not install in both versions of Python only the default one found on your path.

Comment: Just opened my python command line, and I think 2.7 is my default Python installation. Would it be wise to remove 2.7 and stick to 3.5?

Comment: Got it, ty for help!